# How to extract prosodic cues from a wav file using Python

Tags: audio, python, autocorrelation, pitch, feature-extraction

How do I extract the following features as from wav files in Python -

1. Voicing rate (Voice rate) - frequency of phonemes while speaking, and represents the pace of a conversation
2. Number of autocorrelation peaks
3. Pitch, pitch bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

This project [Speech Signal Processing Toolkit (SPTK)](http://sp-tk.sourceforge.net/) provides several features you are looking for. Here is a good wrapper around it https://github.com/r9y9/pysptk 
This wrapper is using a slightly different version of SPTK, but installation is straightforward.

`pip install pysptk`

1) I would use kaldi or another speech recognition package on phones output and a VAD system to compute the voicing rate.

2) For autocorrelation, convert the waveform to mel-cepstrum with the function [mcep](http://pysptk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pysptk.sptk.mcep.html) then compute the autocorrelation with [c2acr](http://pysptk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pysptk.sptk.c2acr.html#pysptk.sptk.c2acr)

3) Here is an example to compute the Pitch http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/r9y9/pysptk/blob/master/examples/pysptk%20introduction.ipynb